# Power BI Embedded, App Owns Data, Changing Token Expiry

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We implemented Power BI Embedded, App Owns Data following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers).
We embed a report following the exact code in the [App Owns Data](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) github sample project.
However we would like to extend the embedToken expiry time to multiple hours.
We tried the following without success:

```
EmbedToken tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(pbi_groupId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(10);

tokenResponse.Expiration = expiration;
```

But I believe the token is still expiring and the embedded report breaks after aprox one hour.
Should this be working or should it be done in another way?

**EDIT**

After some [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) it seems like this could be done by changing the life for AccessTokens on Azure Active Directory which I understand defaults to 1h. If this is the case I'd appreciate instructions on how to do this on AAD, preferably via de Portal.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by configuring the access token life time in Azure Active Directory. 
I followed the steps in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-token-lifetime-policies) via PowerShell.

- Downloaded Azure AD PowerShell module Public Preview.
- `Connect-AzureAD -Confirm` with my azure subscription credentials to connect to my AAD organization account.
- `New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"10:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "myNewPolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"`

In my case it worked to make it organization default. The same access token requested for Power BI embedded has now a life of 10h.